# How to move a file from a default directory to another?

Tags: c#, file-io

It sounds simple but it is not. I am trying to move a file that i made it like this:

```
string newFileName = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-t{3:00}-{4:00}.txt", 2013, 10, 5, 05, 06);
```

It is going to look like: `2013-10-5-05-06.txt`, from the default directory (`..\bin\debug\2013-10-5-05-06.txt`) to another directory (`c:\Users\Public\Folder`). I want to keep the name of the file so that other files having almost the same name (small difference between) being moved to the same folder. I tried several methods (`Path.Combine(), string.Concat()..`) without success.

Comment: Your question seems to be more about how to create a path rather then moving files around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this snippet

```
string CurrentFileNameAndPath; //the path the file you want to move
string newPath; //only the new the folderPath
System.IO.FileInfo FileYouWantToMove = new System.IO.FileInfo(CurrentFileNameAndPath);
string NewFileNameAndPath = newPath + "\\" + FileYouWantToMove.Name; //remember that using fullname will get the folder and filename
FileYouWantToMove.MoveTo(NewFileNameAndPath);
```

So lets use this as an example i have this file C:/Dir1/file1.txt and I want to change its directory to C:/Dir2/ right? then it will be like this

```
string CurrentFileNameAndPath = @"C:/Dir1/file1.txt";
string newPath = @"C:/Dir2/";
System.IO.FileInfo FileYouWantToMove = new System.IO.FileInfo(CurrentFileNameAndPath);
string NewFileNameAndPath = newPath + "\\" + FileYouWantToMove.Name;
FileYouWantToMove.MoveTo(NewFileNameAndPath);
```

the result will the that file in C:/Dir1/file1.txt will be now in C:/Dir2/file1.txt it have been moved and maintened the same file name  and extension

Comment: is this you mean with: string CurrentFileNameAndPath = Path.GetFullPath(newFileName);

Comment: Yeah it should be the currentFullName o the file you want to change like C:/Users/YourName/Desktop/File.txt

Comment: FileYouWantToMove is newFileName or 2013-10-5-05-06.txt?. i am confused. cannot: newFileName.Name and newFileName.MoveTo().

Comment: File you want to move to is the FileINfo created with the path of the file you want to move to some place which i'm not sure what is the name I'll edit my answer to clarify

Comment: You are simply the best. My problem was that: "\" instead of "/" in the newPath. I take my hat off and thanks for your answers (I spent a lot of time on it).

Comment: @Steve Both of then work as fine but when you use "\" the compiler thinks you want to escape some character like "\n"(or line break) so we use "\\" inseated of "\" when we want to write an "\" so it could work in the same way

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is actually pretty trivial

```
var srcFile = "..\bin\debug\2013-10-5-05-06.txt";
var destFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory));
var destFile = Path.Combine(destFolder, Path.GetFileName(srcFile));
File.Move(srcFile, destFile);
```

Just keep in mind that [Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can throw various exceptions e.g. `IOException` / `UnauthorizedAccessException` etc. so it would be wise to handle these where appropriate.

Comment: Path.GetDirectoryPath: There is no GetDirectoryPath under Path?

Comment: It dosen't work. I tried string srcFile = Path.GetFullPath(newFileName); and i used the rest of the code, but nothing has happened. i just get: the file exists.

Comment: @Steve output the contents of `destFolder` / `destFile` to the console, they should be pointing to the correct directory. The error you are getting is because you appear to be trying to overwrite an existing file, if you want to force overwrite then you should use [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: I tried with File.copy() and i got: Could not find file: the whole path of 2013-10-5-18-19.txt. What is thr problem?  and what do you mean with: "output the contents of destFolder / destFile to the console, they should be pointing to the correct directory."